# actualizar pagina web sin generar tanto impacto en mi server al hacer consultas sql

Tags: jquery, servidor, hosting

necesito que mi sistema haga una consulta en mi base de datos y me traiga los datos cada segundo y lo hago mediante una funcion jquery

```
$('#refrescar').load('datos.php');                  
 var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
 $('#refrescar').load('datos.php');
   } ,1000
 );
```

el hecho es que me trae los datos cada segundo como se lo pido , y lo hago asi ya que otra persona debe recibir esa misma información y debe modificarla y en el proceso necesito mostrar el cambio lo mas rápido posible a la persona que ve la pantalla...

hay alguna forma de hacer esta actualización que no genere ese impacto en mi servidor?

He puesto en practica esto así en un hosting gratuito donde los "hints" o click llegan al limite y cae por que presume un posible ataque Ddos...

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente hacer una llamada cada segundo al servidor puede tener un impacto fuerte sobre este. Para evitar esto yo usaría sockets.

Entiendo que tienes 2 o más usuarios simultáneos, algunos editan y otros tienen que ver lo editado en tiempo real. El usuario que espera los datos actualizados debe estar suscrito a un evento del socket determinado, un evento que se emita con los datos a actualizar cuando estos cambien.

Esto te va a permitir actualizar los datos sólo cuando estos cambien, sin necesidad de estar haciendo llamadas constantes al servidor y evitando así que este lo entienda como un ataque Ddos.

Para implementar sockets con php hay muchas opciones, igualmente hay otras tantas para la parte front, yo te recomiendo [socket.io](https://socket.io/) está muy bien documentado, y hay miles de ejemplos con solo googlear un poco, te dejo un enlace a una librería que he usado yo para implementarlo con php:

https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

Comment: pero eso no es con node.js? 
actualmente tengo un hosting free el cual usa php mysql,
no tendria que cambiar todo lo que esta hecho y como lo tengo hecho para poder usarlo?

Comment: Buenas, no tiene que ser con node, socket.io tiene dos partes, una parte servidora que sí está hecha en node y una parte cliente que es javascript, de socket.io solo necesitarías usar la librería cliente. 

Por otro lado te puse el enlace a una implementación de sockets basada en workerman con PHP, esa sería la parte servidora, si me pasas qué hace la parte de la consulta puedo escribirte un ejemplo más o menos de cómo hacer lo que necesitas.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría que te crees una cache intermedia. Es decir, cada consulta a bbdd que compruebe primero si ya esta cacheada y recuperarla de la cache sin necesidad de repetir la consulta SQL. 
Para poder hacer esto de forma efectiva necesitas un proceso que invalide esta cache cuando se modifique algo en la base de datos. Pero para ayudarte en esto necesitaria saber lo siguiente:
* ¿Eres tu el que actualiza los registros de esta base de datos, es decir la otra persona que hace los cambios utiliza tu misma aplicación?¿O es una aplicación externa? En caso de ser tu el que los actualizas, simplemente necesitas invalidar la cache cada vez que se hacen cambios en la base de datos. Asi la proxima consulta no estará cacheada, se realizará contra la BBDD y quedará cacheada la version actualizada.

Comment: no soy el único que actualiza los registros . no puedo aplicar tu solución, pero gracias por la información , es de mucha ayuda